# How do I get a Soul of a Hero?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

With the Hall of Rites added I need Soul of a Hero to get any previously released character. I have not seen this item yet. How would I go about getting one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're usually offered by events.  I horde mine unless there's a hero I feel like I just have to have.  I've seen events that Souls of Heroes could be found in only twice this year, although I got a few from each.

Basically, make sure to check event rewards, especially for non-specific events (rather than, say, the new Vincent event, which awards FFVII characters and memory crystals, watch for events like Anniversary celebrations and seasonal festivals), and play through the ones that offer Souls of Heroes!

(it helps to have a "main" party capable of clearing the higher level dungeons in those events - I used to keep a lot of my characters the same level and could never get to the end of event dungeons, but now I have a set of five who've broken the level cap I use to grab limited-time rewards like Memory Crystal Lodes and Souls of Heroes.)